# Remove email integration from calendar in mountain lion?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I've just got a new laptop with Mountain Lion. The calendar has the old color coded options of 'Work', 'Home' etc, however it also has my email address as an option. If I select 'Work' and create a new event it automatically changes to the email account, meaning that I get email alerts for events,  which I dont want.

How can I change this behaviour?

UPDATE - Actually I want to completely remove Google Calendar from my mac calendar so i dont get email alerts either. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Remove the Calendar completely.

Go to the Mail, Contacts & Calendars Preference in System Preferences select the google mail account and uncheck the Calendars & Reminders

[image: Contacts & Calendars Preference]

To Set the default Calendar for new events.

In Calendar the default calendar for new events is controlled in the Preferences.

You can set it to ***Selected Calender*** to make new events appear for the calendar you have selected

[image]

or choose a  particular calendar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove Google account from your Calendar, nothing else. Just go to Calendar preferences `cmd+,` then in accounts tab, you can select which account to keep and which to remove. Click on Google/Gmail account and click on the negative sign `-` at the bottom to remove it.

PS: You just reminded me that I need to remove my google calendar too and I just did it. It worked fine, no more google calendar. So it verified the solution too.